Long time behaviour of the integral of the solution to the heat equation
I am interested at longtime behaviour of the solution to the one space dimension heat equation. That is, the solution to the equation $$u_{t} = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx},$$
with initial condition $u(0,x)$ which is not necessarly integrable. By the solution I mean the unique one under the suitable growth condition. This solution can be represented by:
$$u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}p_{t}(x-y)u(0,y)\mathrm{d}y,$$
where $p_{t}(\cdot)$ is the heat kernel.
Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set. Can we say anything about the following limt:
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{B}u(t,x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
Does it converge? To what value? Do we know anything about the convergence of its positve part os opposed to its negative part?
Thanks!

Suppose $u(0,.) \in L^q(dy)$ for some $q\geq 1$ and $u(t,x)=\int_\mathbb{R} p_t(x-y)u(0,y)dy$. Note that $\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}}p_n(y)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $p_n\to 0$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, by Jensen's inequality and dominated convergence we have $|u(n,x)|^q\to 0$ pointwise (in $x$) as $n\to \infty$. Indeed, $(p_t(x-y)dy)_{t>0,x \in \mathbb{R}}$ are probability measures and $p_n(x-y)|u(0,y)|^q\leq \frac{|u(0,y)|^q}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\in L^1(dy)$ uniformly in $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Furthermore, since $|u(n,x)|^q\leq \frac{\|u(0,.)\|_q^q}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ for all $x \in B$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $B$ is bounded (so that $\lambda(B)<\infty$) we again use dominated convergence to obtain $\int_B|u(n,x)|^qdx\to 0$. If $\lambda(B)>0$ another application of Jensen's inequality yields $|\lambda(B)^{-1}\int_Bu(n,x)dx|^q\leq \lambda(B)^{-1}\int_B|u(n,x)|^qdx$ so we have $\int_Bu(n,x)dx\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$; if $\lambda(B)=0$ there is nothing to show since $\int_Bu(t,x)dx=0$.

There are non-integrable choices of $u(0,.)$ s.t. $u(t,x)$ satisfies the representation and the growth condition $|u(t,x)|\leq Ae^{Cx^2}$ but the above conclusion does not hold, in disparate ways. Suppose $u(0,y)=y$. Then $u(t,x)=\int_\mathbb{R} p_t(x-y)ydy=x$ for all $t$. So $\int_Bu(t,x)dx=\int_B xdx$ uniformly in $t\geq 0$. If $u(0,y)=y^2$ then $u(t,x)=\int_\mathbb{R} p_t(x-y)y^2dy=x^2+t$ so $\int_Bu(t,x)dx=\int_Bx^2dx+t\lambda(B)\to \infty$ as $t\to \infty$ (if $\lambda(B)>0$).

Thanks! In your second application of Jense'n inequality - since you don't have a proabablity measure on $B$, aren't you missing a constant in the inequality? something like $\lambda(B)^{q}$?

@mathematico you are welcome! You are correct - I will add the normalisation constant.

Do you know what happens if $u(0,y) \in L^{\infty}$. That is, if the initial condition is bounded? Assume it is also continuous. I have a conjecture that $\lim_{t \to \infty}u(t,x) = \lim_{L \to \infty}\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^Lu(0,y)\mathrm{d}y$ uniformly in $x \in B$, where $B$ is compact set. Hence the integral over $B$ of $u$ converges to this constant times the measure of $B$. Do you happen to known if it is true or how to prove it?

Hello @mathematico, please do post a follow-up question if you want - I will surely think about it and possibly post an answer!

Thanks, posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4935647/longtime-beahviour-of-the-heat-kernel-on-the-real-line-for-bounded-initial-condi?noredirect=1#comment10548622_4935647
