Longtime behaviour of the heat kernel on the real line for bounded initial conditions
Let $u(t,x)$ be the fundamental solution to the heat equation $u_t = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}$ with initial condition $u(0,\cdot)$. That is, $u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}p_{t}(x-y)u(0,y)\mathrm{d}y$ where $p_t(\cdot)$ is the heat kernel defined by $p_t(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}$. Assume that $u(0,\cdot)$ is a bounded continuous function (you may assume finite limits at $\pm$infinity if it helps). I have a conjecture that for every compact set $B$ of the real line, we have that:
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}u(t,x) = \lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L u(0,y)\mathrm{d}y \quad \text{ uniformly in $x\in B$.}$$
I wasn't able to prove this. If anyone knows of a reference for this, a proof (or a counterexample), I will appreciate it. Thanks!
Edit: I found a reference for pointwise convergence https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=4121&option_lang=eng
But I still don't know about locally uniform convergence.

The RHS is simply $u(0, 0)$. Is $u(0, 0) = 0$ in your case?

Why is it $u(0,0)$? And it does not have to be $0$ generally.

$\left \lvert \tfrac{1}{2L} \int^L_{-L} u(0, y)~\mathrm{d}y - u(0, 0)  \right \rvert = \left \lvert \tfrac{1}{2L} \int^L_{-L} u(0, y) - u(0, 0) ~\mathrm{d}y  \right \rvert \leq  \sup_{y \in [-L, L]} \lvert u(y, 0) - u(0, 0) \rvert \rightarrow 0 $ as $L \searrow 0$

It is the limit as $L \to \infty$, not 0

Oh, then I misread, sorry. But if $u(0, \cdot) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the RHS converges to $0$ while the LHS should also converge to $0$ by definition of $p_t$

That is true. I wonder what happens if you don't assume this, and assume bounded and continuous instead, maybe with finite limits at infinity

Then I think the RHS can be everything. Depends on how quickly the integral grows

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
